# Meaning of "line" in a sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

In the episode 7 of *Friends*, we find the following talk:

> Rachel: I just never had a relationship with that kind of passion, you
>   know, where you have to have somebody right there, in the middle of a
>   theme park.
>
> Ross: Well, it was the only thing to do there that didn’t have a
>   **line**.
>
> Rachel: There, well, see? Barry wouldn’t even kiss me on a miniature
>   golf course.

I checked several meanings to the word "line" in some dictionaries but I could not find that appropriate one. I think that "to have a line" isn't an expression. I didn't know what Ross meant. Could someone help me, please? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sense of "line" (American) is synonymous with "queue" (British) -- people waiting for something in first-come-first-served order.  The joke is that indulging in their passion was the only available, um, "amusement" that didn't involve waiting for other people to take their turns first.